# Enter an IP Address and return location of said IP Address in Android Studio

Tags: android, location, ip

I'm working on an application in Android Studio and I'm trying to enter an IP Address into an EditText, press a Button and return the location of said IP Address. I've tried looking for something similar online but all I've found is a bit different from what I'm trying to do so I'm not really sure what steps to take.

Comment: First of all wellcom to stack overflow! Coud you please say what kind of answer you hope for. Do you just want to learn the conceptual steps or what exactly do you hope for?

Comment: Well, firstly I wanted to know if there are any tutorials available that cover what I'm looking for that I might have missed, if not I think conceptual steps would be great.